# Munkres Topology Supplementary exercises chapter 1 question 2 (a). Showing two definitions are the same

Tags: elementary-set-theory, well-orders

Let $J$ and $E$ be well-ordered sets; let $h: J\rightarrow E$. Show the following two statements are equivalent.

- $h$ is order preserving and its image is $E$ or a section of $E$
- $h(\alpha)= smallest(E-h(S_{\alpha}))$ for all $\alpha$

[Hint: Show that each of these conditions implies that $h(S_\alpha$) is a section of $E$; conclude that it must be a section by $h(\alpha)$]

To clarify notation, $S_\alpha$ means the section by $\alpha$.

I got as far as proving the hint suggestion. How do I proceed from there?

Comment: Just to clarify, by "section by $\alpha$" you mean $S_\alpha = \{\beta \in J : \beta < \alpha\}$?

Comment: Yes, that is what is meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you already proved the hint, here is how to proceed.

The first point implying the second is already answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2343589/661457).

For the other direction, let $e < h(\alpha)$ for $\alpha \in J$. Then $e \in S_{h(\alpha)} = h(S_\alpha)$, so $e$ is in the image of $h$. Hence the image of $h$ must be a section (or $E$ itself).

Comment: And if $e$ is not smaller than $h(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha \in J$, would that correspond to the case where the image is all of $E$?

Comment: @Abe Not necessarily, $e$ could also just be above everything in the image. The point is that if the image is not a section, there must be an $e < h(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$ such that $e$ is not in the image.